# How to use ".endswith" within a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, text, character

I'm struggling with this task that i've been given in Python, and it's about modifying text from a given text file (read mode, not write). Here's a piece of my code:

```
file = open("fileName")
suffix_list:[]

for e in file:
    elements=e.split()
    result=elements.endswith("a")
    suffix_list.append(result)
```

And then I want to print the length of the list with suffixes:

```
print(len(suffix_list))
```

Instead i get this error: " 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith' "
I'm really not sure whats wrong here, can someone please help?

Comment: `elements` is a list. You cannot check if it "ends with" a string. Also, `suffix_list:[]` does not create an empty list.

Comment: What is your expected output: a list of lists of strings (one list per line) or a flat list of strings?

Comment: a flat list of strings

Comment: Just to save others a bit of hairpulling: endswith() is all lowercase and case sensitive.

In case you see the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'endsWith'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `endswith` with a string and not a list. `e.split()` gives a list. Iterate through this list and check `endswith` with each item in the list.

```
suffix_list = []

for e in file:
    for element in e.split():
        if element.endswith("a"):
            suffix_list.append(element)

print(len(suffix_list))
```

Also, a list-comprehension version:

```
suffix_list = [] 
for e in file:
    suffix_list.extend([element for element in e.split() if element.endswith('a')])
```

assuming, you need a *flat* list rather than a list of lists.

Comment: Or... a nested list-comp: `suffix_list = [el for e in file for el in e.split() if el.endswith('a')]`...

Answer (score 0):

```
for e in file:
    elements=e.split()
    result=[ele for ele in elements if ele.endswith("a")]
    suffix_list.append(result)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants a flat list as the output, since they want to get the total number of matching words by using `len`. So rather than using `.append` you can use `.extend`.